# Making a rectangle using a given symbol w/ given height and width

Tags: python, higher-order-functions

I'm trying to make a rectangle out of a given symbol with a specific given height and width. The first def function should contain only one parameter. This should be a higher-order function as well.
This is my code so far:

```
def rectangle(x):
    def someName(width,height):
        i = x * width
        while len(i) <= height:
            print(i)
            i = i+1
    return someName
```

If entering something like this to test it, this is how it should print:

```
>>> percent = rectangle('%')
>>> dot = rectangle('.')
>>> print(percent(3,2))
%%%
%%%
>>> print(dot(4,1))
....
```

My code currently returns `None`. How do I get it to return `i`? If I change `return someName` to `return i`, many other errors occur.

Answer (score 1):

`someName` is printing the characters, so calling `print` from the outside is redundant. If you want `someName` to do the printing then change the calls to:

```
>>> percent(3,2)
>>> dot(4,1)
```

On the other hand, if you want caller to call `print` then you'll need to change `someName` to build up a string piece by piece and return it at the end, instead of doing the printing itself. For example:

```
def someName(width,height):
    i = x * width
    lines = []
    while len(i) <= height:
        lines.append(i)
        i = i+1
    return '\n'.join(lines)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the decorator function of python,like this：

```
def decorate(key):
    def real_decorate(func):
        def wrapper(width, height):
            return func(width * key, height)
        return wrapper
    return real_decorate


@decorate("%")
def rectangle(width, height):
    return [width for i in range(height)]


print("\n".join(rectangle(10, 5)))
```